# Performance Tuning Shiny Application for Too Many 'conditionalPanels'

Tags: r, shiny

I have been working on a Shiny application for a complex decision-making tool and, when finished, it will use about 150 `conditionalPanel()` functions, many of which are dependent on ones before it. And most all of them are for conditional `selectInput()` Here is an example:

```
#partial ui.R
##############
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.options_count >= 4 & input.criteria_count >= 2 & input.subCri1 == 'Yes'",
                         uiOutput("OptionAssessment1_1_6"))



#partial server.R
##############
output$OptionAssessment1_1_6 <- renderUI({
    option1 <- strsplit(input$options_text, ", ")[[1]][3]
    option2 <- strsplit(input$options_text, ", ")[[1]][4]
    criteria <- strsplit(input$subCri1a, ", ")[[1]][1]

    selectInput("OptionAssessment1_1_6",
            label = paste0("How much better is ", option1, " than ", option2, " at meeting ", criteria, "?"),
            c("9 (Extremely better)",
              "7 (Much better)",
              "5 (Moderately better)",
              "3 (Slightly better)",
              "1 (Equally as well)",
              "1/3 (Slightly worse)",
              "1/5 (Moderately worse)",
              "1/7 (Much worse)",
              "1/9 (Extremely worse)"),
            selected = "1 (Equally as well)")

})
```

After a certain amount of conditionalPanels, my application never completely loads when ran on my local machine (so forget about on a server at this point).

I have found Shiny documentation on fine-tuning application performance once on the server, but does anyone have experience (or documentation) for tuning a very complex and conditional Shiny app? I'm hoping there may be some way to execute it in stages.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Not sure Shiny has been created to handle such complex applications. You might try to split features into different apps, or setup a big server

Comment: Could you somehow use fewer conditional panels but somehow use `updateSelectizeInput` instead? Maybe once you make choice one, you proceed to choice 2, but what that is depends on a update?

Comment: `shinyjs` could allow you to move the conditions to the server, then use `show` and `hide` to control the HTML components.